# Looker Studio | pivot chart - sorting by metric and last month

Tags: sorting, charts, pivot-table, looker-studio, looker

I have a Looker pivot chart with

Rows (text)
Mary
Anthony
Paul
Beth
...

Columns (date YYYY-MM) ordered from least recent to most recent
2023-11
2023-12
2024-01
2024-02

Metrics (values, numbers)

I would like to sort the pivot table metrics descending from the highest value to the lowest value *for the last month* (in this case 2024-02). So the rows should follow the order of the highest value in the last month.

I am assuming there is a bug in the main Looker Data/Chart options, so I am trying to set a calculated field, but I am doing something wrong, here the attempt

`view: view_name { dimension: YYYY-MM { order_by_field: 2024-02 } }`

I don't know which is the view_name (error)

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvKkP.png)

Or does the formula have to be different (so as not to write the exact last month each time)?

Thank you in advance.